# ASP.NET c# Using Uploadify Jquery Plugin Get Http Error 302

Tags: asp.net, http, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify Plugin in my webform and get a error Http 302. I dont know how this happen and how to fix it, anybody help me fix it. thank in advance. 
Here is my javascript code :

```
<link href="jscript/uploadify/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jscript/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscript/uploadify/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscript/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#custom_file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'jscript/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'admin_ServicesPhotosManager.aspx',
            'cancelImg': 'jscript/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'folder': 'Images/Uploads',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
            'multi': true,
            'queueSizeLimit': 5,
            'queueID': 'custom-queue',
            'onSelectOnce': function (event, data) {
                $('#status-message').text(data.filesSelected + ' files have been added to the queue.');
            },
            'onAllComplete': function (event, data) {
                alert(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded successfully !');
                window.location = 'admin_ServicesPhotosManager.aspx';
            },
            'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info + " file : " + fileObj.type);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my admin_servicephotosmanager.aspx code :

```
 <div id="status-message">
</div>
<div id="custom-queue">
</div>
<input type="file" id="custom_file_upload" name="file_upload" />
<a href="javascript:$('#custom_file_upload').uploadifyUpload();" class="file-upload">
</a>
```

finally is my admin_servicephotosmanager.aspx.cs code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Files["Filedata"] != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploads = Request.Files["Filedata"];
        MessageBox.Instance.DisplayMessageAndRefresh(uploads.ContentLength.ToString(), false);
    }
}
```

**Update** my web.config :

```
<location path="~/admin_ServicesPhotosManager.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"
               maxRequestLength="1048576"
               useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"/>
</system.web>
```

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime
   executionTimeout="110"
   maxRequestLength="102400"
   requestLengthDiskThreshold="80"
   useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
   minFreeThreads="8"
   minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
   appRequestQueueLimit="5000"
   enableKernelOutputCache="true"
   enableVersionHeader="true"
   requireRootedSaveAsPath="true"
   enable="true"
   shutdownTimeout="90"
   delayNotificationTimeout="5"
   waitChangeNotification="0"
   maxWaitChangeNotification="0"
   enableHeaderChecking="true"
   sendCacheControlHeader="true"
   apartmentThreading="false" /></system.web>
```

somebody help me fix http 302 error . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The request probably was blocked, check if you have security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

From your web.config, it will work.